# single sign on without cookie across domain in java and php

Tags: java, php, cookies, single-sign-on

Now I have two categories of subsystem , java and php .
I've searched the internet ,but did not find the solution.
Even someone told me single sign on must base on cookie.
Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Why are cookies not an option?

Comment: @iamien because there are two users in one computer at the same time. If one user have logged in ,another user'login would instead the previous authentication cookie.

Comment: I can give you an answer based on Java sessions using URL rewriting, you can probably do something similar in php.

Comment: "Two users in one computer"? Please explain; this usually isn't a problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If another people get the token in URL,how to recognize the different people with the same URL.

Comment: @Brutal_JL Add a "nonce" or "secure token".

Comment: @chrylis That is to say two users using one computer at the same time.Because there are two monitors connecting to the computer.And they could work on it well.

Comment: Okay. Unless they're using the same browser window, each browser instance will have its own cookies.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Add a secure token before jumping to another subsystem,then analyze the token?

Comment: @chrylis They all use ie ..

Comment: @Brutal_JL More like a one-time use token; that way you prevent that url from being accessed by a "replica".